# Regular expression for all bank card numbers

Tags: regex, banking

I am using a regular expression to match all UK bank card number formats; I have done research and managed to find/amend a regex that covers the majority of formats. However, I have a bit of an edge case where one is not matching and I do not know why, or how to resolve. This is what I am using:

```
(\b[4|5|6](\d){3}[\s|-]?((\d){4}[\s|-]?){2}(\d){4}\b)|(\b(\d){4}[\s|-]?(\d){6}[\s|-]?(\d){5}\b)
```

This is an example card number that does not work: `6759000000005`

This is an example card number that does work: `675900000000555`

Apologies if this is an easy question, I am fairly new to regular expression syntax. Any help to resolve would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you explain with example what do you mean by bank card number? What's the format you looking for and why regex above doesnt work with example?

Comment: You may be better off using a [Luhn check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).  Just because a card matches a regex, doesn't mean it's a valid number due to having to calculate check digits.

Comment: Ideally we would use a Luhn check, but unfortunately for this solution we are only able to use regex. We have done a lot of testing and have a high success rate extracting this number correctly. I was hoping I could amend the current regular expression and make it work for the first example card number I provided.

Comment: Quick answer: your regex looks for a 15 or 16 chars long number. Your first exemple is 13 chars long that's why it can't work. You may play with the repetitions in your regex to use min and max in your matches like `(\d{4,6})` instead of `(\d){6}`. I don't know if you're really using the capture groups of your regex but they sounds strange and may be simplified.

Comment: `[\s|-]` means: *space* or *pipe* or *dash*. Do you really intend the `|` character to be allowed as a separator? (I'm asking because using the pipe unintentionally is a common mistake)

Answer (score 1):

See [here the demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK1iD8/1)

The regex is `(\b[4|5|6]\d{3}[\s-]?(\d{4}[\s-]?){2}\d{1,4}\b)|(\b\d{4}[\s-]?\d{6}[\s-]?\d{5}\b)`

I'm not an expert of UK cards, so I can't tell what is the expected format as you did not gave exemples with spaces or hyphens in them...
If you can refine the requirements it's handlable.

A more generic card number validation (without separators, so you'll need to strip them before) would be

`\d{6}\d{1,12}\d`

As per the requirements of the norm (found nothing on the minimum length of the account identifier):

> An ISO/IEC 7812 card number is most commonly 16 digits in length,[1]
>   and can be up to 19 digits. The structure is as follows:
>
> a six-digit Issuer Identification Number (IIN) (previously called the
>   "Bank Identification Number" (BIN)) the first digit of which is the
>   Major Industry Identifier (MII), a variable length (up to 12 digits)
>   individual account identifier, a single check digit calculated using
>   the Luhn algorithm.[2]

Comment: Thanks for your help and info. Looking at the demo though, the regex does not match 6759000000005?

Comment: Yes as its 13 chars long and I'm unsure where the separator are originally

Comment: @wingmiester I did a change on the last \d to match minimum 1 time and maximum 4 time. Thus allowing numbers from 12 to 16 digits.

Comment: That's great thanks, this has all been very useful and the issue is  now fixed.

Comment: Further testing has revealed that my regex is still not working for all the formats I am testing for. Within this demo is an example of every format I am interested in: [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK1iD8/2). It might be a big ask, but if there is an easy way of matching on the test strings that are not being met, that would be fantastic! The regular expression I have used is my original one because the one mentioned in the answer excludes more than it fixed. I appreciate your help and patience!

Comment: I'll see after coffee ;)

Comment: @Wingmiester there's still no separator (no - nor space) in your test cases, will you have some or not at end ?

Comment: Yes, we will need to accommodate spaces at the end if possible.

Comment: @Wingmiester you're unclear, your current regex include possible separators (- and space) with `[\s-]?` which mean 0 or 1 space or hyphen. If you just need to validate what is in your Regex101 demo, then it's as simple as `\d{min_lenght,max_lenght}`

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood your comment. Yes, we need to cater for possible seperators (- and space).

Comment: @Wingmiester As I only have french cards, I've no idea where the separator could be. I don't know the UK rules of formatting so I can't help without a full input test set ...